# How to pause/restart SingleThreadExecutor (ExecutorService) in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have implemented a Singleton class "SingleTaskExecutor" which is using SingleThreadExecutor to execute one task at a time in order. This class is used to perform asynchronous database operation one at time and in order. Everything is working fine. However now we have a use case wherein we need to pause this service for a while, execute some operation, and then resume the service. Not sure how to pause/resume the service. Here is my code:

```
public class SingleTaskExecutor {

    private SingleTaskExecutor() {}
    private final ExecutorService executor =   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final SingleTaskExecutor instance = new SingleTaskExecutor(); 
    }

    public static SingleTaskExecutor getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.instance;
    }

    public <T> Task<T> create(Callable<T> callable) {
        Task<T> task = new Task<T>() {
            @Override
            protected T call() throws Exception {
                return callable.call();
            }
        };
        return task;
    }

    public <T> T execute(Task<T> task) {
        return (T) executor.submit(task);
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public void awaitTermination() {
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void waitPlease() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
            //executor.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
        //executor.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't suspend an individual task that's already started.  You haven't shown how tasks are submitted and queued, but you should probably just make that code stop submitting tasks while suspended.

Comment: Or have your tasks check for a boolean flag and wait when needed.

Comment: Task<String> task = SingleTaskExecutor.getInstance().create(() -> {
   createOrUpdate(posOrder);
   return null;
  });
  
  SingleTaskExecutor.getInstance().execute(task);
  task.get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to pause executions of tasks, then perform some explicit tasks, and then resume it. I actually see the following solution:

```
private volatile boolean paused;

public <T> T execute(Task<T> task) {
    if(paused) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(paused) {
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
    return (T) executor.submit(task);
}

public synchronized void waitPlease() {
    paused = true;
}

public synchronized void resume() {
    paused = false;
    notify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks llya. Your solution looks good. I am trying this. Will let you know.